# event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation() is not working to stop redirection of pages while clicking on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I am developing one application(in React) where, web pages from different sites are loaded in a iframe(downloading the pages into local system). 
user has to click on the pages and i Will generate xpath or cssPath for the clicked element.
To detect clicks i am adding eventListeners.

**Problem Statement:**
I am able to identify the element and CSS path/ Xpath as well. But if the element is anchor tag which has a href attribute value present. While generating the path, it is also trying to navigate to the page added in href attribute of the anchor tag.

tried:

- `event.preventDefault()`
- `event.stopPropagation()`
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`
- Added click listener and returned false from the listener attached method(my code are in `mouseUpListener` attached function)

Sample code:

```
<iframe  src={iframeSrc} sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" ref='htmlPageRef'/>
```

HTML page contains:

```
<a href='visitMySite.com'> Go to My Website</a>
```

Adding Listener:

```
 frameDoc.addEventListener("mouseup", this.mouseupListener, false);
```

inside the attached method in event listener I have performed `event.preventDefault`, `event.stopPropagation`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Reminder from './reminder';

class TodoCheckList extends  React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('testest');
    }

    callMe(that){
         console.log('test');
        let iframe = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(that.refs.htmlPageRef);
        console.log(iframe);
        var frameDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
        frameDoc.addEventListener("click", this.clickListener, false);
     }


    clickListener = (e)=> {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    render(){
        return (
        <div >

            <iframe onClick={ () => this.callMe(this) } ref='htmlPageRef' src="frameFILE.html" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" width="600"></iframe>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TodoCheckList;
```

Iframe frameFILE content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
        Iframe page
        <a href="google.co.in">Open Google</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `preventDefault` synchronously in a click on a link will definitely prevent the browser's default behavior of following the link. So something *else* is going on, but the code and information in the question is too fragmentary to tell what. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1):

changed `mouseup` to `click` and added `return false;`

```js
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
}, false)
```

```html
<a href='visitMySite.com' id='myLink'> Go to My Website</a>
```

Comment: I have checked that use case as well. It is not wokring.

Comment: updated one sample code snippet, target is to stop redirection of anchor tag